# Uncheck a checkbox field if there's no attachment to a record

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to create an Apex class that will untick a checkbox if there's no attachment related to a record.

Here's the code:

```
public static void handleDelete(List<ContentDocumentLink> records) {
    
    String opportunityKeyPrefix = '006';
    Set<Id> opportunitiesIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    for (ContentDocumentLink record : records) {
        if (String.valueOf(record.LinkedEntityId).startsWith(opportunityKeyPrefix)) {
            opportunitiesIds.add(record.LinkedEntityId);
        }
    }
    
    List<AggregateResult> attachmentPerOpportunity = [
        SELECT COUNT(Id), LinkedEntityId
        FROM ContentDocumentLink
        WHERE LinkedEntityId =: opportunitiesIds
        GROUP BY LinkedEntityId
    ];
    
    Set<Id> opportunitiesWithAttachments = new Set<Id>();
    
    for (AggregateResult ar : attachmentPerOpportunity) {
        opportunitiesWithAttachments.add(Id.valueOf(String.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'))));
    }
    
    Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunities = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    
    for (ContentDocumentLink record : records) {
        if (!opportunitiesWithAttachments.contains(record.LinkedEntityId)) {
            opportunities.put(
                record.LinkedEntityId,
                new Opportunity(Id=record.LinkedEntityId, HasAttachment__c=false)
            );
        }
    }
    
    update opportunities.values();
}
```

I haven't received any errors, the problem is the checkbox doesn't get untick if I removed all of the attachments (Files) in the record.

*NOTE: I already have another apex class that will tick the checkbox if I added a new attachment.*

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line `opportunitiesWithAttachments.add(Id.valueOf(String.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'))));`
will always fail in execution, because that will contain the count of attachments each record has, and cannot be converted to ID. `System.StringException: Invalid id`

Second your code does not throw this error because on deletion `ContentDocumentLink` trigger does not get trigger. Instead `ContentDocument` gets triggered.

So you will have to write logic on `ContentDocument`.